# concatenation in stored procedure mysql

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I want to create concatenation for store procedure mysql.
in php I can use (.) for concatinating the variable 
example :

```
$table = "table_".$_GET["number"];
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,select * from `".$table."` where `field`='$field');
```

in stored procedure mysql, I don't know how to concatinate the variable.

this is my stored procedure script.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `testprocedure`(v_number int(5))
BEGIN
  declare v_table varchar(20);
  set v_table = 'table_'.v_number;
  update `v_table` set `field`=v_number where `field2`='test';
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

so how can I add `v_number` to set `v_table` then add `v_table` to update table query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [CONCAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) : `set v_table = CONCAT('table_',v_number);`

Comment: then, how to pass the `v_table` to update table query?

Comment: you can set your query as a full string : `SET @s = CONCAT('update ', v_table ,' set field=v_number where field2="test";');

PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt;`